# Is a completion of an algebraically closed field with respect to a norm also algebraically closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

Assume we have an algebraically closed field $F$ with a norm (where $F$ is considered as a vector space over itself), so that $F$ is not complete as a normed space. Let $\overline F$ be its completion with respect to the norm.

Is $\overline F$ necessarily algebraically closed?

Thanks.

Comment: Google Ax Sen Tate Theorem.

Comment: The Ax Sen Tate theorem is not appropriate for a solution to this problem. It is quite deep compared to the question that is asked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is yes, and the issue is discussed in detail in $\S 3.5-3.6$ of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/8410Chapter3.pdf) from a recent graduate number theory course.

It is very much as Akhil suggests: the key idea is Krasner's Lemma (introduced and explained in my notes).  However, as Krasner's Lemma pertains to separable extensions, there is a little further work that needs to be done in positive characteristic: how do we know that $\overline{F}$ is algebraically closed rather than just separably closed?

The answer is given by the following fact (Proposition 27 on p. 15 of my notes):

> A field which is separably closed and complete with respect to a nontrivial valuation is algebraically closed.

The idea of the proof is to approximate a purely inseparable extension by a sequence of (necessarily separable) Artin-Schreier extensions.  I should probably also mention that I found this argument in [some lecture notes of Brian Conrad](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/248APage/handouts/algclosurecomp.pdf) (and I haven't yet found it in the standard texts on the subject).

Note that Corollary 28 (i.e., the very next result) is the answer to your question.

Comment: Your notes are very fast becoming a standard text on the subject, so...

Comment: @Mariano: Seriously?  I hadn't heard.  If so, I should really get around to putting in the proof of Hensel's Lemma!

Comment: Google seems to think so! It keeps taking me to them :)

Comment: Pete: include in your answer a link to B's handout on that, which is math.stanford.edu/~conrad/248APage/handouts/algclosurecomp.pdf. As for standard texts which contain a proof, I suspect an argument is in Bosch Guntzer Remmert's Non-archimedean Analysis, although I haven't checked it before writing this comment.

Comment: @K: Okay, I included the link.  As for BGR: it's a standard text for *something* I guess, but not for basic graduate number theory.  (It's also so @$(%*!#^ expensive that I haven't been able to bring myself to purchase a copy, even with university and/or government funds.)  I agree that it seems to be quite good for basic valuation theory: I've been referred to it before...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, (assuming the field is nonarchimedean) this follows from [Krasner's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krasner%27s_lemma). The point is that if some element $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\overline{F}$, then it must satisfy a monic polynomial equation with coefficients in $\overline{F}$; hence it must be very close to satisfying a monic polynomial equation with coefficients in $F$, and in particular must be very close to a root of this second monic polynomial equation (which is in $F$). Now Krasner's lemma implies (if we take this second polynomial *really* close to the first one) that $\alpha \in \overline{F}$.

Comment: Do you assume F is non-archimedean?

Comment: @GEdgar: Whoops, yes, I assumed that. Thanks for the correction.