# Algebraic Closure and Completeness

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

We know a the real numbers are complete, however we also know that the real numbers are not algebraically closed since there are irreducible polynomials over the reals whose roots don't lie in the reals. My question is, is there a relationship between the topological completeness of a field and algebraic closure or lack thereof?

Comment: Well, the complex numbers $\;\Bbb C\;$ are complete too but algebraically closed, so no: there us no relationship.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete and not algebraically closed. $\mathbb{C}$ is complete and algebraically closed.

Comment: Finally, the algebraic closure $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ is a (countable) subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ that is algebraically closed but not complete.

Comment: Complenetess is not topological, e.g. $\Bbb{R}\cong(0,1)$.

Comment: In the nonarchimedean world, $\Bbb Q_p$ (a complete field) has algebraic closure $\bar{\Bbb{Q}}_p$, which is not complete. The completion $\Bbb C_p$ of $\bar{\Bbb{Q}}_p$ is actually algebraically closed though, and this relationship holds rather generally: let $K$ be an algebraically closed field equipped with a nonarchimedean norm which is not complete with respect to that norm. Its completion $K'$ is algebraically closed. See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29722/is-a-completion-of-an-algebraically-closed-field-with-respect-to-a-norm-also-alg).

Comment: @snulty: completeness is not a topological property in general because the notion of Cauchy sequence needs you to have a notion of nearness that can be translated around the space. But this is not a problem in a topological group (where the group operation gives you all the translations you need). Hence using the additive group structure, completeness of a topological field is a well-defined concept.

Comment: @RobArthan that's fairly interesting. Is there some relation between discrete topological groups and their lack of being complete like your example of $\Bbb R$. Is there a good resource on this? I googled and saw some book on topological groups mentioning Raikov completion, is this similar or the same as your notion?

Comment: @snulty: *apologies:* I was wrong in what I implied about discrete topological groups and have just deleted that comment. In a discrete topological group a Cauchy sequence is eventually constant and hence convergent. My other comment stands though - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space. The Raikov completion is the idea I had in mind.

Comment: @RobArthan It might take me some time to unpack what that entourage definition means :)

Comment: @snulty: to cut through the generalisations, in an abelian topological group (which I'll write additively) you can define a sequence $s_1, s_2, \ldots$ to be Cauchy if for any open neighbourhood $U$ of $0$, there is an $N$ such that for any $m, n > N$, $s_m - s_n \in U$.

Comment: @RobArthan That seems to make sense. It also makes it clear where that $V\circ V$ part might be used.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks to all of you.